# Linebreak in table cell at document margin

Tags: tables, line-breaking, margins, boxes

In order to allow line breaks within a table cell, I use `\parbox`. But when the cells I want to have line breaks in are in the last column of the table, the best thing would be to break them at the margin of the document. How can I specify the width of the `\parbox` that it does so automatically, without needing to specify it manually each time depending on the table I'm in?

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\breakcell}[1]{\parbox[t]{22em}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\hrule
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
        A short 1st column & \breakcell{A considerably longer second column where I write way too much stuff}\\
        A short 1st column & Blah blah\\
    \end{tabular}

    \begin{tabular}{ll}
        A considerably longer first column & \breakcell{A considerably longer second column where I write way too much stuff}\\
        A considerably longer first column & Blah blah\\
    \end{tabular}
\hrule
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I see you mention `tabularx` in your answer (`tabulary` is another possibility)  but why use `\breakcell` at all? Normally you would use a table preamble of `lp{22em}` for the table in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the [tabularx](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) package, it's possible to specify the width of the table as such, and then use `X` to tell it which column should be breakable across several lines. If the width of the table is set to `\linewidth` (or `\textwidth`), the last column will automatically break at the margin of the document. For this to work properly, however, it's necessary to either precede the `\begin{tabularx}` environment with a `\noindent` command, or to subtract the width of the indentation from the width of the table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\hrule
    \noindent \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lX}
        A short 1st column & A considerably longer second column where I write way too much stuff\\
        A short 1st column & Blah blah\\
    \end{tabularx}

\newlength{\mylength}
\setlength{\mylength}{\linewidth}
\addtolength{\mylength}{-\parindent}

    \begin{tabularx}{\mylength}{lX}
        A considerably longer first column & A considerably longer second column where I write way too much stuff\\
        A considerably longer first column & Blah blah\\
    \end{tabularx}
\hrule
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Can you afford to use `linegoal`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{linegoal}

\newcommand{\breakcell}[1]{\parbox[t]{\linegoal}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\hrule
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
        A short 1st column & \breakcell{A considerably longer second column where I write way too much stuff}\\
        A short 1st column & Blah blah\\
    \end{tabular}

    \begin{tabular}{ll}
        A considerably longer first column & \breakcell{A considerably longer second column where I write way too much stuff}\\
        A considerably longer first column & Blah blah\\
    \end{tabular}
\hrule
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's interesting to see that the text with your solution stretches somewhat further than it does with ``tabularx`` ...