# Break multicolumn text at document margin with tabularx

Tags: line-breaking, margins, tabularx

I'm using [tabularx](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) to break the content of a column at the document margin (cf. [Linebreak in table cell at document margin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103272/linebreak-in-table-cell-at-document-margin)). But when I use `\multicolumn` in such a table, the instruction to break the text in that column is ignored. How can I enforce it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\newlength{\mylength}
\setlength{\mylength}{\linewidth}
\addtolength{\mylength}{-\parindent}

\hrule
    \begin{tabularx}{\mylength}{lX}
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer & adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac\\
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac}\\
    \end{tabularx}
\hrule

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

In response to Mico's question:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\newlength{\mylength}
\setlength{\mylength}{\linewidth}
\addtolength{\mylength}{-\parindent}

\hrule
    \begin{tabularx}{\mylength}{llX}
        Lorem ipsum dolor & sit amet, consectetuer & adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit\\
    \end{tabularx}
\hrule
    \begin{tabularx}{\mylength}{llX}
        Lorem ipsum dolor & sit amet, consectetuer & adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit\\
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit & \multicolumn{2}{p{\mylength}}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit}\\
    \end{tabularx}
\hrule

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The issue arises because the column type of the `\multicol` statement is `l`, which is not set up to allow line breaks. Use `\multicol{2}{p{\mlength}}{...}` instead.

Comment: @Mico: Assuming you mean "\mylength", that seems reasonable, but then the text is actually broken in (and not at) the margin. The text stretches further than ``\hrule``. And correct me if I'm wrong, but using ``{p{\mylength}}`` would also not be applicable in a table where only _some_ of the columns are multicolumns.

Comment: Well, the poor line break happens because LaTeX isn't set up by default to hyphenate a four-letter word (`elit,`); I trust your actual document has "real" text... Regarding your second comment: Could you post an actual example? I don't see why the `p` column type couldn't be applied in such a more general setup.

Comment: I'll take your word for the ``elit,`` thing (although I thought LaTeX would push the word into the next line rather than extend it into the margin?). I've posted an actual example above now. Note that the second table also messes up the line breaking in the _first_ row, for some reason ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following is a version of your second MWE. Note that because the width of the entire `tabularx` environment is given by `\mylength`, you mustn't use that parameter for the combined width of the second and third columns. To compute the correct width, I make use of two extra length variables, `\xlength` and `\ylength`. `\xlength` is set to the width of the first column (+`4\tabcolsep`); then, `\ylength` is computed as `\mylength-\xlength`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\hyphenation{ad-ip-is-cing} % no idea if this is correct...

\newlength\xlength
\settowidth\xlength{Lorem ipsum dolor sit}
\addtolength\xlength{4\tabcolsep}

\newlength\mylength
\setlength\mylength{\linewidth}
\addtolength\mylength{-\parindent}

\newlength\ylength
\setlength\ylength\mylength
\addtolength\ylength{-\xlength}

\begin{document}
\hrule
\begin{tabularx}{\mylength}{llX}
Lorem ipsum dolor & sit amet, consectetuer & 
adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit & 
\multicolumn{2}{p{\ylength}}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
    consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit}\\
\end{tabularx}
\hrule
\end{document}
```

**Addendum** A couple of answers to the OP's follow-up questions:

- The calculation of `\xlength` along the lines given in the code above is *needed* because the first column, which is of type `l`, doesn't have a pre-specified width. If you're willing to change its column type to `p`, the width of that column could be used directly to calculate the width of the multicolumn.

  E.g., if the width of the first column is given by `\xlength` (up to you to choose its value...), you might start the `tabularx` environment as follows:

  ```
  \begin{tabularx}{\mylength}{p{\xlength}lX}
  ```

  Note that `\xlength` now is purely the width of the first column, i.e., it does not include the term `4\tabcolsep`.

  Then, later on in this `tabularx` environment, you could specify the width of the two-column `\multicolumn` (of type `p`, as in the earlier example) as follows:

  ```
  \multicolumn{2}{p{\dimexpr\mylength-\xlength-4\tabcolsep}}{<stuff>}
  ```
- The term `4\tabcolsep` is the sum of

  - `1\tabcolsep` at the left-hand edge of the table,
  - `2\tabcolsep` for the amount of whitespace between columns 1 and 2, and
  - `1\tabcolsep` at the right-hand edge of the table.

Comment: +1 Next time I'll fix things so that you can use X to span any number of columns and it will do this calculation for you. Next time.....

Comment: One issue here is that you need to find out post-hoc what the length of the non-multicolumns are by correctly locating the cells with the widest text widths. Ideally this should somehow be done automatically, which I think (hope!) is what David says he will do in the next version (!) of ``tabularx``.

Could you briefly explain the ``4\tabcolsep`` thing? Why exactly that?

Comment: @Sverre - I've provided an addendum to address your follow-up questions.

Comment: @Mico: Nice addendum. Your more detailed explanation will be valuable also to others who google things like ``4\tabcolsep`` (like I tried first).